Combinacion de 4 tablas en looker para grafico de series temporales
Tengo problemas para crear un grafico de series temporales en el que me muestre la cantidad de reviews de un restaurante VS otros 3 (tengo cuatro tablas entonces, con las mismas columnas pero no los mismos datos) necesito visualizarlo en looker. como tendria que hacer los join y que campos creen que tengo que añadir en metricas, dimensiones y periodos?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
